# Import "telegram" could not be resolved and Import "telegram.ext" could not be resolved

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I get errors when I run this

import logging
from telegram import Update, ParseMode
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters

and I already did the

pip install python-telegram-bot in the terminal

I just want it ot run so I can run my telegram bot

Answer (score 0):

This might vary based on your OS, but try doing this instead

```
pip3 install python-telegram-bot
```